# DHIS Pivot table returning an Internal Server Error when moving "Organization Unit" to a "Row dimensions"

Tags: dhis2

While working on a pivot table, everything works fine until I move the "Organization Unit" to a "Row dimensions",

This doesn't happen for all "Data" types, this happen when an indicator has a denominator with "Org unit count" multiplied by certain number. My guess is the Org unit count is causing the problem: the URL looks like:

`http://localhost:8080/api/29/analytics?dimension=dx:kNP2St7IlNy&dimension=ou:OU_GROUP-wZp7fX5yYNw;i4ZXz5bTKDB&dimension=pe:2018Q1&displayProperty=NAME&skipMeta=true&includeNumDen=true`

Looked at the developer tools and server is returning a 500 error.

Server log looks like this, cannot find anything useful as per my knowledge (also attached)

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.hisp.dhis.analytics.DataQueryParams.lambda$addDimension$3(DataQueryParams.java:1307)
>       at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)
>       at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220)
>       at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1454)
>       at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175)
>       at org.hisp.dhis.analytics.DataQueryParams.addDimension(DataQueryParams.java:1307)

At this point, the pivot table freezes and the "Loading..." icon keep showing.

I replicated this problem on the latest version of DHIS2 (2.30) as well as 2.28 both on Ubuntu server 16.04 and a MacOS.

[image: Org Unit on Row dimensions]

[image: Problem always happen if i put org unit count in the denominator of the indicator am trying to get a report to]